# $L$ elliptic diff op $\implies$ singsupp$(u)\subseteq$singsupp$(Lu)$ for distributions $u$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

If $L:D'(\mathbb{R}^n)\to D'(\mathbb{R}^n),n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a weakly elliptic, linear differential operator with constant coefficients then for every $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, and for all $u\in D'(\Omega)$ one has $${\rm sing\,supp}(u)\subseteq{\rm sing\,supp}(Lu).$$

I think it's due to Malgrange but I'm not sure.  I can't find it for the life of me.  Is it a named theorem?  Can anyone provide me with a source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Definitions vary in the literature: could you give the definition of *weakly elliptic* that you are using?

Comment: Nonzero symbol for every nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh found it.  It's in Taylor's PDE volume I, chapter 3, or so it seems.  I don't have the book in front of me.

EDIT: No, that's the one.  And we have equality rather than just containment.

Comment: The notion of ellipticity in that chapter (page 245) is: $|P(\xi)|\ge C|\xi|^m$ for some $C>0$, where $m$ is the order of the operator. This is within the hypoelliptic setting, in which the singular support of $u$ and $Lu$ is actually the same. (Covered in Hörmander's second volume of *Linear PDO*, among other places.)

Comment: Ah-ha!  Thank you very much.  I'll check it out at the library tomorrow (and edit the above post).

Comment: Alright, I got it.  I didn't realize I was working with a homogeneous operator and so I was looking at a nonzero symbol but only for the top part of my differential operator, which is equivalent to the condition you wrote.